# Convert Rails Date String to NSDate

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

I have this code which works great in iOS 6 for converting this Rails json supplied date string to an NSDate (2012-12-11T08:28:16-08:00):

```
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ"];
return [formatter dateFromString:string];
```

But it doesn't work on iOS 5. I can't find any good resources for converting that date in 5. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the colon from the timezone at the end before parsing the string.

It was easier for me as I was parsing +01:00 but you can use

```
[dateString componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"]
```

to get an array of components, the last one being the timezone, remove the colon

```
[timeZoneString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@""]
```

Then append all the components back together with "-" replaced in between each one.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 6.0 uses UTS version tr35-25 for formatting. Using 5 'Z's for the timezone parses something like -08:00. i.e.:

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"];
```

iOS 5 and 5.1 use version tr35-19, which doesn't specify anything for -08:00, although 3 'Z's are used for something like -0800.

Does changing the amount of 'Z's work?

You can find the formatting specifications here:

[UTS #35-19](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-19.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

[UTS #35-25](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Comment: Unfortunately no, changing the number of Z's doesn't seem to work. Thanks though.

Comment: No problem... it sounds like a hack, but maybe use [NSString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: withString: options: range:] to replace the last ":" with an empty string and then use ZZZ as the timezone?

Comment: @Pablo ah only just saw this after posting my answer, i think this is the only way.

Comment: CocoaNub: glad it worked!
@JamesP: No problem! Cool thing is that it has been solved, and I was not too off the mark!

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"];    
NSString *clearedString = [railsDateString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@"" options:0 range:NSMakeRange(22, 1)];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:clearedString];
```

a cleaner James P Version